# PayFlow PayPal recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I have made a recurring payment and it gives me approved as response message even if the credit card number and/or cvv code are incorrect in both sandbox and live mode.

Why am I not getting Invalid credit card as response?

[ScreenCast](http://screencast.com/t/mSMq6H8CdPew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify the credit card while creating the recurring profile in Payflow you need to pass the parameter **"OPTIONALTRX=A"** .

With this parameter passed first the card verification will be done and then the recurring profile will be created if everything is ok with card .

Comment: Hi Ehsan, thank you for your reply. But this doesn't validates CVV and ExpiryDate. Could you please also let me know how to do that?